# Diverse loading-screen tips and who does that?

Tags: game-design

Smaller games and projects have been seen to add jokes and tips that are not directly game related and in any form advice to their loading screens. For some reason I can't think of a tripple A title? Anyone else?

Some people around the industry think its bad taste... I've seen arguments where companies have senseless aggression as core gameplay but get iffy about throwing harmless jokes into splash screens. It was really weird.

Can you name a big game that does it?

Comment: All *The Sims* titles and other Maxis games have had various ridiculous stuff shown in loading screens. "Reticulating splines" is pretty [legendary](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Reticulating_splines).

Comment: I've already gotten more than I need, and have accepted the first thing that came along.

Comment: You may want to use a more common word than 'diverse' in the title. The intended meaning is definitely not among the more common ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything recent by Bethesda:

Fallout 3[image]
Fallout New Vegas, [image]

Skyrim[image], 
Dishonored[image].

Comment: Some examples would be great here

Comment: These images do not seem to contain any jokes or anything that seems even remotely out of place. Are you sure you read the question's contents and not just its title? I don't think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @HugoZink Perhaps I don't know what is meant by 'not directly game related' or 'in any form advice'. For example, they are game related (don't know how 'directly' they are) and they aren't advice.

Answer (score 0):

[Borderlands 2](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Load_Screen_Messages) does this.

> The Gunzerker skill "Sexual Tyrannosaurus" regenerates health upon taking damage. But hopefully you saw the skill name and were just like, "I want that."
>
> Shields are like friends: the best ones come with additional benefits.

The game is humorous in itself, which is probably a major factor.